# Getting the weight(percentage) of 1 variable from 3 numbers

Tags: php

I am building a feedback system: positive, neutral and nagative, I want to get the positive percentage somehow.

```
$positive = 4;
$neutral = 1;
$negative = 1
```

So I am trying to get something like 50%. I have tried

```
$positive / $neutral + $negative;

$positive / $neutral + $negative * 10;
```

None seem to get the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $positive = 4;
    $neutral = 1;
    $negative = 1;

    $total = $positive + $neutral + $negative;  
    $percentage = ($positive - $negative) / $total * 100;

    echo sprintf("%02.2f%%", $percentage);

?>
```

Output:

```
50.00%
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to count `$neutral` to positive feedback use this:

```
$total = $positive + $neutral + $negative;  
$percentage = ($positive + $neutral - $negative) / $total * 100;

echo sprintf("%02.2f%%", $percentage);
```

Comment: If positive goes to 5 it goes to 42% rather than 58%

Comment: @FacelessSir Do you count the neutral to positive or to negative or only to the total amount ?

Comment: Neutral and negative are both positive numbers: ie: 1 or 2 etc.

Comment: @FacelessSir No I mean do you count the neutral feedback to positive feed back or to negative or only to the total amount?

Comment: For an example, if user receives a negative feedback their row will go to 1 if they get another then it'll be 2 etc same for positive and neutral

Comment: @FacelessSir Now it should be what you want